# return false but submit

Tags: javascript, forms, email, subscribe

i try two way to solve this problem

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" id="testId" name="testId" placeholder="Email"  />
    <button id="btnValidate" type="submit" onclick="return check();">subscribe</button>
</form>
```

and other way is

```
<form method="post" onsubmit="return check();">
    <input type="text" id="testId" name="testId" placeholder="Email"  />
    <button id="btnValidate" type="submit">subscribe</button>
</form>
```

my js is

```
 function check() {      

    var email = document.getElementById("testId").value;

    var exptext = /^[A-Za-z0-9_\.\-]+@[A-Za-z0-9\-]+\.[A-Za-z0-9\-]+/;

        if(exptext.test(email)==false){


        alert("error");

        document.addjoin.email.focus();

        return false;

    }else{
        alert("complete");

        return true;            
    }

}
```

alert show "error" but submit wrong email.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: `event.preventDefault();` should serve you purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove the `onclick="return check();"`

Then you just need to add `document.getElementById("btnValidate").onclick = check;` to your js and it would work

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="post" id="form">
  <input type="text" id="testId" name="testId" placeholder="Email"  />
  <button id="btnValidate" type="submit">subscribe</button>
</form>

<script>
  let form = document.querySelector('#form');
  form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    check();
  });
</script>
<script>
   function check() {      

    let email = document.getElementById("testId").value;

    let exptext = /^[A-Za-z0-9_\.\-]+@[A-Za-z0-9\-]+\.[A-Za-z0-9\-]+/;

    if(exptext.test(email) === false){

      alert("error");

      document.addjoin.email.focus();

      return false;

    } else {
      alert("complete");

      return true;            
    }

  }

</script>
```

This should work